# How to add another column to histogram by ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a date.frame with some columns.I want to plot all columns `trt resp se` on y axis and the forth column `class` on  x axis:
here i succeeded to plot a histogram of `trt vs class`. What I need is just add `resp se` to the same histogram but with different colours.Is it possible to add a legend with a title `group`?

```
df <- data.frame( trt = c(-1, -1, 2, 2), 
resp = c(-1, 5, -3, 4), class = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
se = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2) )
ggplot(df,aes(class,trt))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",position='dodge')
```

Comment: You are plotting a "barplot" not a histogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you wanted each bar to start on the x-axis:

```
 #transform to long
library(reshape2)
df.2 <- melt(df,id.var="class")

ggplot(data=df.2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=class,y=value,fill=variable),stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

yields

[image]

If you want them stacked that can be done too, but is more tricky due to the negative values.

Comment: Thanks that worked fine. I wonder how to add a subscript to `trt` so it becomes `trt2` but `2` as a subscript.

Comment: I think that's a new thing in itself, there's a lot of resources on formatting text in ggplot. And please (not to beat my own drum, but to prevent others from spending time on questions that have satisfactory answers) mark the answer you find best as correct using the green checkmark under the vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your commands you are using a bar plot not a histogram.
Hope this is good for you:

```
    library(ggplot2)

    df <- data.frame( trt = c(-1, -1, 2, 2), 
                      resp = c(-1, 5, -3, 4), class = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                      se = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2) )

 ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = class, y=trt, fill="trt"),stat="identity",position='dodge') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = class, y=resp, fill="resp"),stat="identity",position='dodge') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = class, y=se, fill="se"),stat="identity",position='dodge') +
  labs(fill = "col") + # change legend title
  ylab("VALUES") + # change y axis title
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","green","blue")) # pick your colors
```